# Python: How to extract names from certain email addresses from your Inbox using IMAP?

Tags: python, email

I get a lot of emails where the sender looks like this:

```
Jenna Klopf <noreply@rentlinx.com>
Sam Smith <noreply@rentlinx.com>
```

I want Python to automatically read my emails and if "noreply@rentlinx" is present in the Sender
to extract the names "Jenna Klopf"and "Sam Smith" and save them in a list. How do I do that?
As of right now I can search for emails containing "noreply@rentlinx.com", see code below.

```
import imaplib, email
user = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
imap_url = 'imap.mail.yahoo.com'

def auth(user,password,imap_url):
    con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
    con.login(user,password)
    return con

def get_body(msg):
    if msg.is_multipart():
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0))
    else:
        return msg.get_payload(None, True)

def search(key,value,con):
    result, data = con.search(None,key,'"{}"'.format(value))
    return data

def get_emails(result_bytes):
    msgs = []
    for num in result_bytes[0].split():
        typ, data = con.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        msgs.append(data)
    return msgs

con = auth(user,password,imap_url)
con.select('INBOX')
result, data = con.fetch(b'1859','(RFC822)') #1859 is the newest email, I have 1860 emails in total
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
msgs = get_emails(search('FROM','noreply@rentlinx.com',con))
for msg in msgs:
    print(get_body(email.message_from_bytes(msg[0][1])))
```

Comment: Where do you want to search for these names?  In a header (which one?) The message body?

Comment: The names are right beside the "From" email. For example Jenna Klopf is right beside <noreply@rentlinx.com>. Is there a way to extract it from there instead of going through the body and searching for it?